How count adjacent points with the same values and label them according to the count in Python
I have the following script and sample data:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Generating dummy data for testing
ROWS=10
COLS=20
X = np.random.randint(2, size=(ROWS, COLS))

# Visualizing
df = pd.DataFrame(data=X)
bg='background-color: '
df.style.apply(lambda x: [bg+'red' if v>=1 else bg+'yellow' for v in x])


My problem is:
How do I count the adjacent points (i.e., points with the same values and no gaps), group them, and label them according to the counts using python.
Here's the expected image for the input above:

I'll appreciate any help that you can provide.

First get the contiguous regions with scipy.ndimage.label, then find the counts with np.unique (see duplicate). output

Inspired by @mozway's suggestion, you could something like this to Styler your table.

hello, that suggestion of mozway works for my application. Thanks for the recommendations! will that too!
